# sturm-liouville with negative weight function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

Suppose the following SL problem

$$
 y''(t) + \lambda w(t)y(t)=0 \\
y(0)=0, \qquad y'(1)=0
$$
with $w\in C([0,1])$ a weight function.

If we take $w=f$, for a certain $f\in C([0,1]), f>0$, it is well-known that all the eigenvalues are positive and ordered.
If now we take $w=-f$, can we infer that

1. the eigenvalues are all negative;
2. the eigenvalues are those for the choice $w=f$, but with opposite sign?

Can you also provide references for this?

Thank you

Comment: It is trivial, just replace $\lambda$ by $\eta=-\lambda$ and $w$ by $-f$ and you get back the same equation as you originally had but now the eigenvalue is $\eta$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that
$$
     \int_0^1 y''(t)y(t)dt+\lambda \int_0^{1}w(t)y(t)^2dt=0.
$$
Then,
$$
       \left.y'(t)y(t)\right|_{0}^{1}-\int_0^1y'(t)^2dt+\lambda\int_0^1w(t)y(t)^2dt=0 \\
          \lambda\int_0^1w(t)y(t)^2dt=\int_0^1y'(t)^2dt \\
           \lambda=\frac{\int_0^1y'(t)^2dt}{\int_{0}^{1}w(t)y(t)^2dt}.
$$
If $w < 0$, then $\lambda < 0$.

Try looking at $w\equiv 1$ and at $w\equiv -1$.